# Why ng-class is not getting applied to input tag?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my HTML input tag on which I have created conditional ng-class

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="label" name="label"
     ng-required="true"  ng-class="{ missing: $ctrl.flag=='true'}"
     ng-model="$ctrl.DataToSend.label[$ctrl.language]" />
```

And here is my CSS

```
.missing {border: solid 1px red;}
```

When my $ctrl.flag is true ng-class should get applied but it's not happening. Why?

Comment: give us working snippet  in fiddle or codepen.!!

Comment: Thank you Prabhakaran for the reply I am new to StackOverflow can you please tell me how to add fiddle or codepen

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the class which you want to apply in quotation marks. Otherwise it looks for an AngularJS variable where the string for the class name is contained.

Also make sure your condition is not always false. In your case the `$ctrl.flag` variable might store a boolean value. So change your condition to: `$ctrl.flag`

Updated Code:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="label" name = "label" ng-required="true"  ng-class="{ 'missing': $ctrl.flag }" ng-model = "$ctrl.DataToSend.label[$ctrl.language]"/>
```

Comment: @VishalArthamwar Then propably your condition is always false. Does the variable `$ctrl.flag` contain a boolean? Then change the condition to: `$ctrl.flag===true`

Comment: @Simon as per your comment I have tried this also but dont have any effect on GUI

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snippet.

[Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/knyojb9e/)

Snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.flag = true;
  $scope.toggleClass = function() {
    $scope.flag = !$scope.flag;
  };
});
```

```css
.missing {border: solid 1px red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
    {{flag}}
    <input type='text' class='form-control' ng-model='test' ng-class="{'missing': flag}" />
    <button ng-click='toggleClass()'>
      Change
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will work

Comment: Thank You Jayant but the requirement is that flag is gets changed automatically in controller.based on some processing and not on explicit button click. Can we do that without button click

Comment: it'll work @VishalArthamwar... change the scope of flag value on your condition. But still figuring the way to use $ctrl as explained in angularjs doumentaion

Answer (score 0):

I found the Issue with my code there is some other CSS which is overriding to my 'missing' css when changed the overridden CSS its started working fine.

```
input[type="text"].missing {border: 1px solid #ff0000;}
```

Previously it was

```
input[type="text"] {border: 1px solid #ddd;}
```